# Duplicate records in a table with identity column as PK

Tags: sql-server, group-by, insert, primary-key, identity

One of our developer inserted few million rows from a table to a target table.
He inserted using a while loop in batches and now in the target table there is some 5 million duplicate rows.The issue is that the PK is identity column and while inserting he didn't do

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT DBO.TABLE_NAME ON`

So now in the table there are duplicate entries with a distinct identity column value.

If i group by as shown below :

```
group by COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7
```

i can get a unique row.

Can someone help me to create script to delete the duplicate records.

Comment: Post sample data and clarify which rows you consider duplicates and you want to delete.

Comment: This is not a scripting service site, try to come up with a solution and ask for help if you run into a particular error

Comment: This has nothing to do with SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON. The code that inserted clearly had a flaw that inserted duplicate records, and you don't have any unique index to enforce uniqueness. There are plenty of other questions answered here on how to delete all but one duplicate row, but the problem statement here is not very accurate or clear.

Comment: @pmbAustin : If the insert script had `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON ` the insert would be done on the target table with the same ID from the source.Then it would have been easy to delete.

Comment: You didn't make that even remotely clear in the question. As stated you made it sound like you thought that was the reason duplicates were generated. Please go back and edit your question to clarify what it is, what you are asking, and show examples. Nobody can help if nobody has a clue what you're asking or why.

Comment: So why do you not ask your "developer" to write the script? Or maybe both of you could work on this together and learn from the experience as well? Seems like there is room for improvement here.

Answer (score 0):

Create `#temp` table of your final distinct records of your table. After that delete all the records from your table having duplicate `id`.

After that you may use this `#temp` table to re-enter this record in your existing table.

`set identity insert on/off` is upto you.

For hint search for `checkident`.